# Use gulp-run-command in a function with Gulp 4?

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, gulp

I try to use *gulp-run-command* to run a command with Gulp 4. I can't figure out how to create a function that allows to run the command.

My `gulpfile.js`:

```
const run = require('gulp-run-command').default;

function fooFunc() {
  run('echo "Hello World!"');
}

exports.foo1 = fooFunc;
exports.foo2 = async() => run('echo "Hi!"')();
exports.foo3 = async() => fooFunc();
```

Running `gulp foo2` works, but when I try to run `gulp foo1` I get the error:

```
The following tasks did not complete: foo1
Did you forget to signal async completion?
```

Running `gulp foo3` doesn't output an error, but doesn't really do anything either.

What's the right syntax to move the `run` call into a function?

Answer (score 0):

Found the answer:

```
const run = require('gulp-run-command').default;

function fooFunc(done) {
  run('echo "Hello World!"')().then(done);
}

exports.foo1 = fooFunc;
```